# I am interested in hiding and the showing a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to hide and then show a div using jQuery, what would be a
proper way to do this?

```
$("#div_myDiv").hide();
$("#div_myDiv").show();
```

Comment: you want to show and hide the div by clicking on some button?

Comment: `$('#myDiv').fadeOut('slow').delay(3000).fadeIn('slow');`

Comment: FYI, you don't need js/jQuery for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div_myDiv").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will not take a time to hide and show by Default its (200) which make the effect hide and show fast without notice it .. you can use  hide callback function

```
$("#div_myDiv").hide(3000 , function(){
   $(this).show(3000);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/2du2fg5j/)

> Note : instead of .hide()  you can use fadeOut() or slideUp() .. and
>   instead of .show() you can use fadeIn() or slideDown();